# can not write frame to video?

Tags: c++, opencv

i'm new with opencv. I write code for write and save videos from frame but is, only create a 0kb avi file and not write down any frame to videos. is there any bug in my code and how can i fix it?

```
Mat img; outp output;
int frames_num = (int)Cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
int frames_cnt = 0;

cv::VideoWriter outTrainVideos; 
int codec = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'P', 'E','G');
string filename = "D:/AiMotionData/#Hammer/outVideos.avi";

bool out = outTrainVideos.open(filename, codec, 10, output.img.size(), true);

while (!mWorkerThStopReq && Cap.isOpened())
{
    if(frames_cnt++>= frames_num && frames_num > 0)
        break;

    // Read frame
    if (!Cap.read(img))
        continue;
    // Process frame
    if (!run(img, &output))
        continue;

    outTrainVideos<<output.img;
}   
outTrainVideos.release();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: does your application have access to the opencv_ffmpeh* dll? Is the frame writing line of code reached?

Comment: yes, thanks for your help. i fund the bug! my image size is only read inside the loop! :)